# UITextField doesn't enter edit mode

Tags: google-maps, uitextfield

I have a ViewController all it's layout is done programmatically because it serves for google map.

I'm placing buttons, Layers and other views on the map as subviews, all works great.

The goal is to click on a button which then adds the UITextField as subview, **only** when the user click in it the carriage appears as well as the keyboard by setting it to becomeFirstResponder

Current state the UITextField appears but it's not entering edit mode, I tried adding a tapGesture and it didn't work either

This is the code for adding the UITextField

```
- (IBAction) searchBtn_Click:(id)sender
{
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchTextField];

}

-(UITextField*) searchTextField
{
    if(_searchTextField == nil)
    {
        //set the location where to place the textField as well as its size.
        CGFloat yAxis = self.yAxis - TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT - TEXT_FIELD_PADDING_Y;
        CGFloat textFieldWidth = (ROUND_BUTTON_SIZE + ROUND_BUTTON_PADDING_X)*(NUMBER_OF_MENU_BTN-2) +ROUND_BUTTON_SIZE;

        //set all parameters to give it a interface builder look & feel 
        _searchTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.screenMarginXAxis+5, yAxis, textFieldWidth, TEXT_FIELD_HEIGHT)];
        _searchTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        _searchTextField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
        _searchTextField.placeholder = @"enter address or location";
        _searchTextField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
        _searchTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;
        _searchTextField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        _searchTextField.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
        _searchTextField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
        _searchTextField.delegate = self;
    }
    return _searchTextField;
}
```

this is the code i tried for the tapGesture, it was added after adding the subview in the `searchBtn_Click:` method

```
//set the tap gesture to identify when the user enters edit mode
    tapSearchTextField = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(enterSearchEditMode)];
    [tapSearchTextField setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [tapSearchTextField setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    [tapSearchTextField setDelegate:self];
    [self.searchTextField addGestureRecognizer:tapSearchTextField];

-(void) enterSearchEditMode
{
    [self.searchTextField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling that "`[self.searchTextField]`" is NULL wen you attempt to add a gesture recognizer to it.  Setting a breakpoint there and/or NSLog'ing the output would prove this.

Are you referring to "`searchTextField`" property anywhere outside of your view controller?

If not, get rid of the "`@property`" bit and stick with using the ivar "`_searchTextField`" (e.g. change lines like "`[self.searchTextField addGestureRecognizer:tapSearchTextField];`" to "`[_searchTextField addGestureRecognizer: tapeSearchTextField];`".

Comment: the property is not NULL, I'm referring to it only from the view control and unfortunately I started with it not being a property it didn't work so I changed and gave it a go any other ideas?